# If statement for a string from a JTextField

Tags: java, if-statement

So, I have a small application and I made an "extra" JTextField for the user to input Yes or No if he wants extra data.

I use this method:

```
process(file.getText(), Integer.parseInt(aText.getText()),
                    Integer.parseInt(bText.getText()), cText.getText(),
                    dText.getText()); //dText is the one I have problems with
```

In

```
public void process(String name, int a, int b, String obs, String extra) { ... }
```

I wrote this

```
if(extra== "yes"){
            writer.write("Success!");
        }
```

but it is not working.

If I was to write just

```
writer.write(extra);
```

it would have worked, by that it means that it can read the text I input but still I can't use the If-statement.
Am I doing something wrong or that is not possible at all?

here is my full code : http://pastebin.com/esw302uD

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `extra.equals("yes")` instead of `extra== "yes"`